# Is it possible to use a liquid "where" array filter with nested properties?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm trying to filter an array of blocks using block settings. I can filter by properties like "type" using the following syntax:

`{% assign example = section.blocks | where: "type", "photos" %}`

What I need to do is filter by block settings, something like this:

`{% assign example = section.blocks | where: settings.collection, collection.handle %}`

The above example is failing silently.

**A note:** Currently I am accomplishing what I need using a capture with a for loop and an if statement, and then assigning with a split — but the code is so bloated, and doing all that for a simple filter operation seems ridiculous. I find myself constantly feeling like I'm fighting with liquid, and I guess I'm hoping it might be just a bit more elegant than I'm giving it credit for.

Comment: could you please post how you achieved this with the capture/for loop/and an if statement? I'm trying to figure out how to generate a list of products filtered by their metafields...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know much about Ruby, but it seems you [can't](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb#L181) pass nested properties with dot notation to the `where` filter. However, after [seeing people](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/pull/230#commitcomment-3711006) accessing nested values using `map`, I tested mixing the two, and the [map filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/map/) seems to work well for this case.

I have a boolean setting called `default` in my blocks, and I got the settings object for the last block with `default` set to `true` using this:

```
{% assign obj = section.blocks | map: 'settings' | where: 'default' | last %}
```

Of course, then you can't get data outside of the settings object that was extracted. For that I think you really would need to loop through the `section.blocks` and find filter manually using the `if` tag.

Comment: Very useful! To complete this answer, here's how I would access any settings of the matching block: `{% assign obj = section.blocks | map: 'settings' | where: 'setting_id', 'setting_value_to_match' %}{% assign my_setting = obj | map: 'any_setting_id_of_matching_block' %}`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. `where` will work only at the root element. In your case `section.blocks` is the root element so `where` can be used for something like `section.blocks.abcd_property`.

**Rough example:** `{% assign example = section.blocks | where: 'collection', collection.handle %}` will load all section blocks having their *collection* property as *collection.handle value*

This will work

```
{% if settings.collection == collection.handle  %}
{% assign example = section.blocks %}
{% else %}
{% assign example = '' | split: '' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks - that answers my question. I was hoping liquid allowed for using the where array filter with nested properties, but I guess not. Also I'm not "doing it wrong." Like I said in my question I have it working with essentially the same logic you suggest. I was hoping there was a syntax in liquid that allows for comparing nested properties with 'where' — a simple "no" would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Previously used `map` which loses outer data but found string notation works with `where` for nested properties:

E.g., Using a `posts` collection where each `.md` file has the front-matter:

```yaml
header:
    isArchived: true
```

The following `liquid` snippet filters archived posts via `header.isArchived`:

```
{% assign archived = site.posts | where: "header.isArchived", true %}
```